# How can I clone a microSD card from a 32GB card to a 128GB card so that all saved/cached data is recognized on a Motorola/Lenovo Moto G5 Plus?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I've tried using file explorer with hidden and system files viewable to copy across all files from the 32GB to 128GB microSD card but when I try to view offline videos in YouTube for example it's greyed out and I have to re-download.

Comment: Don't use the Windows Explorer. Use a HDD clone program like TrueImage.

Comment: I tried Macium Reflect but that didn't work. It doesn't support microsd or exfat.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Linux and Android. On Android you need one of the following:
a) Two micro-SD card slots
b) One micro-SD card slot and one USB cardreader with a USB-OTG adapter
c) A USB hub with two USB cardreaders on a USB-OTG adapter

On Android `Termux` from the Play Store can be used for this, on Linux open a terminal.

1. Use `lsblk` to find out the drive names for your two SD cards.
   Here I will assume `sdd` is your old SD card and `sde` the new one.
2. Clone the old card onto the new one 1:1: `dd if=/dev/sdd of=/dev/sde bs=1M`
3. Resize the partition with `fdisk` - Execute `fdisk`, then hit `d` to delete the partition (this won't actually delete any data!) and return to confirm. Then hit `n` to create a new partition. Select `p` for primary and then hit return three times to create the partition. Then hit `w` and return to write the changes.
4. Resize the new partition: `resize2fs /dev/sde1`

That's it. Please note that if you want to do this on your android device, you need root.

Comment: Will this work for EXTFS file system? I didn't think Linux supported it as it needs paid licence from Microsoft.

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz EXTFS has nothing to do with Microsoft. EXTFS was introduced "April 1992 with Linux". It works flawlessly on Linux. Maybe you confuse it with NTFS? NTFS works on linux too, it needs drivers and I'm not sure about Android (might be included by default in android though) but on Linux you can install the `ntfs-3g` driver for full compability.

Comment: My apologies I meant EXFAT - https://www.google.com/search?q=exfat

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz EXFAT is also very well supported on Linux and Android by default, you can clone and resize it without any additional drivers. (Edit: apparently that's not true for all Linux distributions. Here the packages `exfat-utils exfat-fuse` should be installed)

Comment: Does resize2fs support resizing on exfat? These comments on another question suggest not - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201708/problem-with-files-after-transfer-to-new-sd-card

Comment: @DarrynBrisdaz Apparently you're right. Another option would be to format the new sdcard first so that its partition fills up the entire space, then tun `dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=/dev/sde1 bs=1M` to copy the data and simply skip step 3. and 4. from my answer.